# Background size:Contain issue in IE with frame

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, background-image, background-size

I have used background size:contain in div background image to maintain aspect ration and fill the div.

```
<iframe src="myfile.php">
</iframe>
```

in myfile.php

```
<div style="background-image: url(URL_TO_SHOW); background-size: contain;">
```

Background image got filled with maintained aspect ration in FIREFOX and CHROME, but there's some issue in IE. I tried on IE11.

I think frame's size is used in background-size, and hence image got stretched according to frame instead of DIV.

Comment: Make a fiddle to show what is happening :)

Comment: Understandable plz show in fiddle